# Document with 2 asymmetrical/slanted columns?

Tags: formatting, two-column

I was wondering if it is possible (I think so) and how to have to asimmetrical/slanted columns on a page in a LaTeX document like in the following picture:

[image]

What's the easiest (i.e.: no Tikz) way to achieve such result? Thanks to anyone in advance!

Comment: Did you try shapepar? Are you aware of [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4644/how-do-i-fill-a-shape-with-text-like-a-circle)?

Comment: [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231734/121799) may even be closer to what you want.

Comment: You may also look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60905/121799) to see a discussion of the difficulties and/or ask @PrzemysławScherwentke to translate [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60821/121799).

Comment: Just read the paper, seems to be the answer but I don't get a word of Polish and asking the translation for such a long piece of work is overwhelming... By the way, happy new year!

Comment: I've been working off and on (mostly off) on a version of parshape/shapepar which can handle multiple paragraphs and non-uniform line spacing.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your contribution! Any progress?